# Interpreting "Total Fragmentation" column when rebuilding an index in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, fragmentation, rebuild

I can't find it now but somewhere in the comments of a post in stack overflow someone said the .85 is 85% when checking the Total Fragmentation column you see when right clicking on an index in SSMS and hitting Rebuild. But I can't find anything else that says that.

So I want to know, is .85 == 85% and 1.25 == 125% fragmentation?

Or is .85 == 0.85% and 1.25 == 1.25% fragmentation?

I'm sure this is a dumb question as most everything else states the latter in an implied way, but I just wanted to double check.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag due to the mention of "SSMS" in the question

Comment: If you are using the gui in SSMS to rebuild indexes you need to read this article. https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why people avoid answering the questions directly, but your answer is, 0.85 in EM is just like it says, 0.85%

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to check fragmentation - it should be easy to use it to verify your results via the UI:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType, 
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.indexes IND
ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id 
AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id 
WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 5 
ORDER BY 1,2 DESC
```

This works on the current database.